# Words that mean "to comprehend" that imply a certain level of understanding

Tags: connotation

There are lots of words that mean "to comprehend" (and [questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/237924/word-that-means-to-understand-deeply-on-an-intellectual-level/) asking about such words), but it's hard to find examples that make the connotation of such words clear.

What words have a connotation (or explicit definition, I suppose) that implies a level of understanding, eg. a shallow understanding, an intuitive understanding, a deep understanding of all aspects of the issue, etc.

The example that comes to mind is "grok", which was coined by Heinlein in *Stranger in a Strange Land* and means "to understand fully". Are there other words (preferably that are relatively widely used; grok counts, but most authors aren't fortunate enough to coin a word that will be used outside of their work) that mean a specific level of understanding?

Example words that come to mind, but for which I don't have a good idea of what level of understanding they imply (if any) include:

- compass
- cognize

Comment: Master/proficient/skilled vs. novice/learner/neophyte come to mind. A thesaurus will yield a bounty.

Comment: Thanks! I browsed through a thesaurous before hand, and a few (proficient is a good one I didn't think of or see) were obvious, but mostly the definitions were just variations on "to understand, comprehend" with no description of the level of understanding implied.

Comment: Someone suggested "internalize" to me out of band, which I think has a connotation that means "to fully understand". Other suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps **Assimilate** :  (tr) to learn (information, a procedure, etc) and understand it thoroughly.